# jquery iframe modal demo works, downloaded version doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

[I like this simple iframe modal](https://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Simple-iFrame-Modal-Plugin-With-jQuery-modallink.html), I especially like being able to close the modal from inside the iframe, however I can only get that to happen in the demo page at jqueryscript.net; when I download it the close button inside the iframe modal does nothing, I can't figure out why.

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. Click the F12 and look in the console for errors - you likely need a library in the right place. For example the iframe content ALSO needs jQuery

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you'll also need a server _(remote or local)_, or it will block communications between the iframe and the parent page, for security reasons → `Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame`. Firefox is not as strict, so it'll work without a server.